# Implementing Doubly Linked List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, linked-list

My take on Doubly Linked List in Python. Is there a more efficient and compact way to do this? Are there any bugs in my program if so how can i fix it?

**PS:** I'm a beginner in Object Oriented Programming, so i might have gaps in my knowledge, please explain any new concept i failed to add to my implementation, Thanks.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.prev = None
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class Doubly_Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.length = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        CurrentNode = self.head
        while CurrentNode != None:
            yield CurrentNode.data
            CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        length = self.length
        if index > length-1:
            raise IndexError("Index Exceeds The Length of Linked List")
        elif index < 0:
            if index < -length:
                raise IndexError("Index Exceeds The Length of Linked List")
            else:
                count = -length
                CurrentNode = self.head
                while count != index:
                    CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next
                    count += 1
        else:
            count = 0
            CurrentNode = self.head
            while index != count:
                CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next
                count += 1
        return CurrentNode.data

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __str__(self):
        CurrentNode = self.head
        result = []
        while CurrentNode != None:
            result.append(CurrentNode.data)
            CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next
        return f'{result}'

    def find_index(self, value):
        if not self.length:
            return -1
        index = 0
        CurrentNode = self.head
        while CurrentNode.data != value:
            CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next
            index += 1
            if CurrentNode == None:
                break
        if CurrentNode != None:
            return index
        else:
            return -1

    def append(self, value):
        head = self.head
        NewNode = Node(value)
        if head == None:
            self.head = NewNode
        else:
            PrevNode = head
            CurrentNode = head.next
            while CurrentNode != None:
                PrevNode = CurrentNode
                CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next
            PrevNode.next = NewNode
            CurrentNode = NewNode
            CurrentNode.prev = PrevNode
        self.length += 1

    def insert(self, index, value):
        head = self.head
        NewNode = Node(value)
        length = self.length
        if index > length-1:
            raise IndexError("Index Exceeds Length of Linked List!")
        elif index < 0:
            if index < -length:
                raise IndexError("Index Exceeds The Length of Linked List")
            else:
                self.insert(length+index, value)
                return
        elif index == 0:
            if head == None:
                self.head = NewNode
            else:
                NewNode.next = head
                head.prev = NewNode
                self.head = NewNode
        else:
            if index == length-1:
                self.append(value)    
            else:
                PrevNode = head.prev
                CurrentNode = head
                NextNode = head.next
                count = 0
                while count != index:
                    PrevNode = CurrentNode
                    CurrentNode = NextNode
                    NextNode = NextNode.next
                    count += 1
                PrevNode.next = NewNode
                NewNode.next = CurrentNode
        self.length += 1

    def delete_index(self, index):
        head = self.head
        length = self.length
        if index > length-1:
            raise IndexError("Index Exceeds the Length of Linked List!")
        elif index == 0:
            self.head = head.next
            self.head.prev = None
            head.next = None
        elif index < 0:
            if index < -length:
                raise IndexError("Index Exceeds The Length of Linked List")
            else:
                self.delete_value(self.__getitem__(index))
                return
        else:
            if index == length-1:
                PrevNode = head
                CurrentNode = head.next
                while CurrentNode != None:
                    PrevNode = CurrentNode
                    CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next
                PrevNode.prev.next = None
                PrevNode.prev = None
            else:
                PrevNode = head.prev
                CurrentNode = head
                NextNode = head.next
                count = 0
                while count != index:
                    PrevNode = CurrentNode
                    CurrentNode = NextNode
                    NextNode = NextNode.next
                    count += 1
                NextNode.prev = PrevNode
                PrevNode.next = CurrentNode.next
        self.length -= 1


    def delete_value(self, value):
        if self.length == 0:
            return False
        else:
            index = self.find_index(value)
            if index == -1:
                raise ValueError(f"{value} is not in linked_list.")
            else:
                self.delete_index(index)
                return True
```